# django-filter field with widget 'SelectMultiple' gives pre-selected values from passed queryset

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-filter, bootstrap-tags-input

I am implementing filters for a given set of objects using django-filters. For one of the field I am using bootstrap tagsinput with multiple select.
So, first in my filters.py (code below) I have passed the queryset in ModelMultipleChoiceFilter with the widget SelectMultiple.
But when I load the page, the select comes with pre-selected (selected="selected") options with all the queryset objects value in it.

So, I basically want these select multiple options to be 'unselected' by default.

Thanks in advance.

```
#filters.py
class JobFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    job_category = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Interests.objects.all(),
                                                            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': "form-control",
                                                                                               'data-role': "tagsinput"}))

    class Meta:
        model = JobPost
        fields = ['job_category', 'job_type', 'intake', 'duration']

#html as per inspection mode
<select name="job_category" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" 
    id="id_job_category" multiple>
    <option value="45" selected="selected">Interests object (45)</option>

    <option value="46" selected="selected">Interests object (46)</option>

</select>
```